# Wrong limit result?

Tags: output

I'm trying to evaluate the following limit:

```
Limit[(d + 1/2)*Log[d + 1/2] - (d - 1/2)*Log[d - 1/2],d->a]
```

Normally, when a tends towards 0.5, the limit is supposed to give 0 (which it does when I put a=0). However, when a=0.49999999999999833` (precisely), it gives me the result "Indeterminate". Why is it giving me that result? Can I do something to avoid it? (It creates problems afterwards)

Comment: I do not reproduce the issue: https://imgur.com/a/zvGtZlk

Comment: This is odd. Are we on the same version? I'm using Wolfram Mathematica 12

Comment: Ah, here we go again... [thread on meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/should-indicating-the-version-of-mma-be-compulsory)

Comment: Isn't the version 12 the latest version tought?

Comment: Are you calculating a [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy)?

Comment: I am indeed calculating a von Neumann entropy (Also a Rényi, for which I had similar problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit) works for inexact numbers, but the issue is probably related to:

```
Limit[Log[d - 1/2], d->0.49999999999999833`]
```

> -∞

There was a change in how machine numbers are handled starting in M11.3, and this change means the output of your limit will be different when comparing M12 and M11.1 and earlier.

Now, [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit) works best with exact input. If you want to use inexact input, though, it is probably better to use an extended precision number. So:

```
Limit[Log[d - 1/2], d->0.49999999999999833`16]
```

> -34.0 + 3.1 I

and:

```
Limit[(d+1/2)*Log[d+1/2]-(d-1/2)*Log[d-1/2],d->0.49999999999999833`16]
```

> -6.*10^-14 + 5.*10^-15 I

both produce answers more in tune with your expectations.

Comment: While using the extension is indeed working, the problem is that the number I gave as a example is the result of long calculations and is part of a big table of numbers. Is it possible to non-manually add those extensions?

Comment: @Alex Use [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision)

Comment: Ha, this is working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take a limit here, you can just use a multiple dispatch function to "plug the holes" at $a=\pm\frac12$:

```
f[1/2 | 0.5] = 0;
f[-1/2 | -0.5] = I*π;
f[a_] = (a + 1/2)*Log[a + 1/2] - (a - 1/2)*Log[a - 1/2];
```

This is also much faster and easier:

```
f[0.5]
(*    0    *)
f[0.49999999999999833`]
(*    -5.83346*10^-14 + 5.2318*10^-15 I    *)
```

Comment: You could also use ``f[n_?(Internal`RealValuedNumberQ[#]&&Abs[#]==.5)]:=...`` instead of the two `Alternatives` patterns, either of which could be missed for something like `.49999999` which will probably also give poor behavior.

Comment: @b3m2a1 in general you're right; in practice `Log` is such a tolerant function that in this case even `f[0.5 + 2^-53]` and `f[0.5 - 2^-53]` evaluate correctly. You cannot get any closer to $\frac12$ with machine precision. So there is no issue here.